# why does my main object, invoke all methods of another object, when only one is actually invoked?

Tags: scala, object, intellij-idea, program-entry-point, software-design

Day 1 of learning scala :
This is my code, but I get unexpected results in one scenario.

```
object Hello extends App {
  def square(x: Int) = x * x
  println("Hello, World!")
}

object main extends App {
  println(Hello.square(2))
}
```

then the output is (correct )

```
4
```

but when I run main without Hello extending App as well,

```
object Hello {
  def square(x: Int) = x * x
  println("Hello, World!")
}

object main extends App {
  println(Hello.square(2))
}
```

I get this.

```
Hello, World!
4
```

What is happening? Why is main executing everything inside the Hello object, when I simply evoked the Hello.square function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an `Object` is essentially using a static class so all the code inside it evaluated when the object is constructed. So, actually the expected result is for the `println` to happen regardless if you call something on the object or not.

The question then, is how come you don't see this behavior with

```
object Hello extends App {
  def square(x: Int) = x * x
  println("Hello, World!")
}
```

well, the only difference is the `extends App` and indeed in the documentation we can see

> **Caveats**

> It should be noted that this trait is implemented using the
> **DelayedInit** functionality, which means that fields of the object will
> not have been initialized before the main method has been executed.

So when your first implementation builds on a limitation of the App implementation - which will probably change as

> Future versions of this trait will no longer extend DelayedInit.

It is better to put any "free" code in Hello inside functions to prevent the unintended side effect you see

Comment: I see! I did read the DelayedInit property, but I couldn't connect the dots as I did not know that an object is essentially a static class with all values initialized the first time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that everything in the object block is evaluated when you reference the object. And

```scala
object Hello {
  def square(x: Int) = x * x
  println("Hello, World!")
}
```

behaves like

```scala
object Hello {
  def square(x: Int) = x * x
  val _ = println("Hello, World!")
}
```

because `println()` produces a side effect and returns `Unit`/`()`, which in this case is discarded right away. So the printing is just a side effect that is produced when evaluating the object. Also take note of the following example:

```scala
object Hello {
  def square(x: Int) = x * x
  println("Hello, World!")
}

object main extends App {
  println("first")
  Hello
  println("second")
  println(Hello.square(2))
  println("third")
}
```

this prints

```sh
first
Hello, World!
second
4
third
```

so the printing of hello world happens only once and it happens when `Hello` is referenced, not when `square()` is called.

Normally, you would not want to have code that produces side effects within an object. This is more a place for functions and values/variables. E.g.:

```scala
object Hello {
  val w = "World"
  def greet(what: String): Unit = println(s"Hello, $what!")
}

object main extends App {
  Hello.greet(Hello.w)
  Hello.greet("Scala")
}
```

Or if you want the value to be dynamic, you can use a class instead:

```
class Hello(val w: String) {
  def greet(what: String): Unit = println(s"Hello, $what!")
}

object main extends App {
  val h = Hello("World")
  h.greet(h.w)
  h.greet("Scala")
}
```

**Edit: Changed some incorrect details of the initial answer.**

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful. I did not know that the print statement essentially becomes val _ = println("Hello, World!") ... or that objects initialize everything the first time they are invoked!

Comment: That `val _ =` stuff is not correct, or at least is very misleading. The `println` does not introduce  a new member to the class, it is just part of the construction code for the class.

Comment: @AnweshaBhattacharya as @Tim points out correctly, the `val _ = println()` may be misleading. What I meant with that, is that `println()` resolves to a value `Unit` (which is Scala's value for nothing/no value) that is not used any further. But he's right that it's not strictly equivalent. So maybe ignore this part. I'll update my answer. But I hope it's still a useful answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. So I take it that the first time an object is used, it basically runs though everything it has, executes any function it has, initializes any variables it has. And thus, if it has any side effects it executes that as well.